# Ansible, checking inventory groups and hosts

Tags: python, linux, elasticsearch, ansible

Are there any possible ways to check if registered variables (hostnames) with a loop are in inventory and print their groups?

I am creating a role to install heartbeat with ansible role. But it will be installed only on one jumphost which will ping the other.

Inside this role i have created separated files and put config for each host in them. But i need to add some fields to to find out which group they belong to (we need it in Kibana).

I used Jinja templates but it paste the group that owns the host I play the role.

```
{% for group in group_names %}
    group: {{ group }}
{% endfor %}
```

so I started to search if there is any way in ansible itself to do it.
I

```
- name: list of hosts
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

it returned hosts and i would like compare this list with list in our inventory and get their group names to paste them to the icmp.yml configs of heartbeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q; *Are there any possible ways to check if **registered variables (hostnames) with a loop are in inventory** and **print their groups**?*

A: Yes. It's possible to use [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)

> **ansible_play_hosts_all**: List of all the hosts that were targeted by the play
>
> **group_names**: List of groups the current host is part of

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[item].group_names }}"
  loop: "{{ hostnames }}"
  when: item in ansible_play_hosts_all
```